# adding a foreignkey set to serializer in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am making a movie-related website and well, every movie or tv show has some trailer videos.
I have two models which look like the code provided below. I need to make an API which retrieves an instance of a movie with all it's details. I have done everything that's needed for that and the only thing remaining is returning the details of the trailer videos.

The trailer model has a foreignkey field which points to the movie its related to. but I dont know how I can add each movie's video details to the retrieve instance api.

Any idea on how I could do that?

Models.py

```
class Film(models.Model):
    filmID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    seasons = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    statusOf = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(4), MinValueValidator(1),])
    typeOf = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(4), MinValueValidator(1),])
    numberOfFilminoRatings = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    filminoRating = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(0),])
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(0),])
    releaseDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    details = models.TextField()
    salePercentage = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    saleExpiration = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    filmGenre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    filmActor = models.ManyToManyField(Celebrity, related_name='actor')
    filmDirector = models.ManyToManyField(Celebrity, related_name='director')
    filmProducer = models.ManyToManyField(Celebrity, related_name='producer')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} {self.releaseDate.strftime('%Y')}"

class Video(models.Model):
    videoID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    qualityHeight = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    qualityWidth = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    sizeOf = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    directoryLocation = models.TextField()
    
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Serializers.py

```
class FilmRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = ('filmID', 'title', 'price', 'seasons', 'duration',
                  'statusOf', 'typeOf', 'numberOfFilminoRatings', 'filminoRating',
                  'rating', 'releaseDate', 'details', 'salePercentage', 'saleExpiration',
                  'filmGenre', 'filmActor', 'filmDirector', 'filmProducer')
        read_only_fields = ('filmID',)
```

Views.py

```
class FilmRetrieveViewSet(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.FilmRetrieveSerializer
    queryset = Film.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'filmID'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to add a serializer for the videos and also set its source to be the video_set queryset!!

```
 class VideoSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
          class Mete:
                model = Video
                fields = ()
    class FilmRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        videos = VideoSerilazer(many=true, read_only=true, source='video_set') #SOURCE ADDED
        class Meta:
            model = Film
            fields = ('filmID', 'title', 'price', 'seasons', 'duration',
                      'statusOf', 'typeOf', 'numberOfFilminoRatings', 'filminoRating',
                      'rating', 'releaseDate', 'details', 'salePercentage', 'saleExpiration',
                      'filmGenre', 'filmActor', 'filmDirector', 'filmProducer', 'videos')
            read_only_fields = ('filmID',)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create video serializer and add it to fields in filmretrieveserializer.

```
class VideoSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
      class Mete:
            model = Video
            fields = ()
class FilmRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    videos = VideoSerilazer(many=true, read_only=true)
    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = ('filmID', 'title', 'price', 'seasons', 'duration',
                  'statusOf', 'typeOf', 'numberOfFilminoRatings', 'filminoRating',
                  'rating', 'releaseDate', 'details', 'salePercentage', 'saleExpiration',
                  'filmGenre', 'filmActor', 'filmDirector', 'filmProducer', videos)
        read_only_fields = ('filmID',)
```

Comment: But does this give me the trailer videos that are for this movie?

Comment: yes it will give

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't work. I just want to point it out again that the film is foreign key in the video model and not the other way around.